# Password reset by sending an SMS

Tags: php

Im designing a password reset system where the user can provide en email and phone number, and a verification code will be sent by SMS. However I just noticed a flaw in this system. If somebody knows my email, they can just type it in and reset it with their phone. Is there some way this can be securely implemented?

I dont have any code, this is more of an abstract question.

Comment: Include a confirmation link in the email sent. This way, even if someone asks for a password reset, it won't actually happen until the account user validates it from the email.
Or, make a temporary token... you have many ways to do what you want !

Comment: my system is either send an email with the token or send the token to the phone. :(

Comment: You need to have stored the users phone number _before_ they request an activation code. That way the phone number would only text the specified phone number (assigned to the account) and the email would only email the specified email (assigned to the account). You wouldn't need to know both and you can't get the info of the assigned email/phone number just because you know the other one.

Comment: yes, storing the phone in the database is one way of solving this... but if the user doesnt want to store their phone but wants to use the sms reset?

Comment: Then they can't use SMS reset - you might as well just say "type in the numbers 0123 to reset the password" if you want that kind of security.

Comment: @M.Mar well now that's his problem if he doesn't want to have a secure access....

Comment: true, ill just include a phone number column in users table, and if such number exists, they will get an sms

Comment: Sounds good to me !

Answer (score 0):

M.Mar you can validate the mobile/email as part of the registration so that they are linked to the user account. Once that's done, you know the password reset will go to the linked verification method.

When I've done it previously, I also allow the user to select which verification method to use - sms / email.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to solve this by only allowing users with their phone numbers saved in DB to reset by SMS

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use email verification

   1.1 you can send password reset url to your email 
    if you are valid user, you can enter in mail and click link.
    this will lead you to set new password.
   1.2 you can send random verification code (like outlook verification)
    you have to provide pair of email address and verification code to reset password
2. you can send verification code to mobile.
   user have to provide pair of phone number and verification code to reset password